# Failing to call a method in test class

Tags: java

I was trying to make a complex class for complex numbers. After creating the mult method giving the product of two complex numbers it fails to run. In this code below, when i define s as: s=mult(u,v), eclipse point an error and I don't understand why. Can anyone give a help?

```
package gestion.complexe;
public class Complexe {
double reelle,imag;
public Complexe(double reelle,double imag) {
    this.reelle=reelle;
    this.imag=imag;
}
 public Complexe() {
 this(Math.random( )*(2-2),Math.random( )*(2-2));

}  
 public String toString() {
 String s=reelle+" + "+imag+"i";
 return s;
}
  // Sum of two complex
  static Complexe somme(Complexe c1,Complexe c2) {
 return new Complexe(c1.reelle+c2.reelle,c1.imag+c2.imag);

} 
  // Product of two complex numbers
 static Complexe mult(Complexe u,Complexe v ) {
 return new Complexe(u.reelle*v.reelle- 
 u.imag*v.imag,u.reelle*v.imag+u.imag*v.reelle);
}
 public boolean estReel(Complexe z) {
 return z.imag==0;    
 }
// magnitude of two complex numbers 
 public double module () {
    return Math.sqrt(this.reelle*this.reelle + this.imag*this.imag);
  }

       
}
```

here is the class test

```
package gestion.complexe;
// Test Class
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Complexe u=new Complexe(1.0,1.0);
Complexe v=new Complexe(3.0,4.0);
Complexe r=new Complexe(1.0,0.0);
// The problem is the next line, eclipse point error
Complexe s=mult(u,v);
System.out.println(s.toString());

}

}
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: Please paste your code, no image ;)

Comment: The code doesnyt where to find the method do `Complex.mult()`

Comment: Also, save your modified files before attempting to compile

Comment: Please add some details to your question and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mult` is a static function of the `Complexe` class. To use it, you have to use the class as a prefix like this:

```
Complexe s = Complexe.mult(u, v);
```

Comment: Thanks f1sh. It works. Now if I dont want to use the Complexe prefix, how could be declaration of mult

Comment: @DINEDINE then you need to define the `mult` method in the `Test` class, which is not what you want.

Comment: Clear. I understand now lot of things. Thank you